# dart_api.h not found when build library dart_sqlite

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu, dart

As i ask before,  to use dart-sqlite,  I must install dart-ext:sqlite first. But every time I try to build it, I found error= Can not found dart_api.h. how to fix it?

I install it on ubuntu 12.04.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't follow the build instructions:

> Either edit build.sh to point to the SDK, or set the environment variable DART_SDK.

Once you correctly point `DART_SDK` to the `dart-sdk` directory of your local Dart installation, the build system will find `$DART_SDK/include/dart_api.h` just fine.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I installed dart editor, dartium, dart-sdk via ppa with apt -get install on my ubuntu. I can't find all file that needed. So that's all apps( I think) installed on system, not standalone. May you show me where I can find that path? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Debian-based systems, but I believe `dpkg-query -L dart-sdk` will list the files in that package.

Comment: Ok... thank you. By trace my installation step, now I know this apps is dartsdk not dart-sdk. And now I can find dart_api.h. Thank you.